# boost python local dictionary's this and c++ object's this is different?

Tags: c++, boost

Hi i'm using boost python to bind my class.

I bind the class and each member functions with boost python.

```
class Control
{
   private:
       boost::python::dict m_localDictionary;
   public:
       Control() { cout<<"constructor this : "<<this<<endl;
       ~Control();
       void CallEvent()
       {
         boost::python::object globalObject = 
          boost::python::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");

          //insert this pointer to local dictionry
          m_localDictionary["this"] = this;

          //debug
          cout<<"this: "<< extract<Control*>(m_localDictionary["this"]) <<endl;
       }
}
```

And i create Control object in c++ side and call the function.

```
Control control;
control.CallEvent();
```

But the result come like this.

```
constructor this : 068567D8

this : 075409F0
```

It means although that i put control object's this to it's local dictionary, but in local dictionary's this is
not same. I must use object's this keyword in python.

Why this is not same between c++ this and python local dictionary's this?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a typo or a bug that `m_localDictionary["this"]` is not in parentheses for the `extract` function call. It looks peculiar syntax.

Comment: @acraig5075 well.. i put c++ data in local dictionary to use in python, 
on the contrary, i extract data from local dictionary like this. 1. get data from dictionary by object type ( m_localDictionary[ key name ] )  2. this is a object type so i extract real data with extract<T>( object ) function

Comment: This is available for normal value type. But if the type is pointer then it can cause a problem.

Comment: What I mean is you have `extract<T>object` and not `extract<T>(object)`.

Comment: Oh it's my typing mistake, and i fixed it. thanks.

Comment: uhm.. but the problem is still alive. Maybe i think c++ is unmanaged language but python is mananged language so boost python will create new rapper managed object when i create new c++ instance.